# passing values using jquery or ajax to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass value from one JSP page to another page using jquery.In below code I would like to pass the variable "processId"  to another page. The value should pass to another page after the below JSP page is loaded.

I am getting error: "procId is undefined"

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=passValue;
function passValue()
{
$.post("Testing.jsp", {processId: ""+procId+""});
}
</script>
</head>
<%
String processId = "555";
%>
<form name="fm" id="fm">
<input  type="hidden" id="procId" value="<%=processId%>" name="processId">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: JSP files are supposed to be invoked only by Servlets (MVC). Are you sure you want to call them directly from the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery calls should be placed within the standard block:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //jQuery code here
});
```

With this block, the code won't execute until the DOM is fully loaded; you don't need to assign a function to window.onload.

Next, to grab the value of the input with id "procId", you need to create a jQuery object using the regular syntax: `$('#procId')`, then access its value with `.val()`

So this should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post("Testing.jsp", {"processId": $("#procId").val() })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

not sure. but you can try the following

```
$.post("Testing.jsp", {"processId": ""+$("#procId").val()+""})
```